# Cloud Hosting for ASP.Net website developed in C# 3.0

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0, cloud-hosting

I have designed website in ASP.Net 4.0 on Framework 4.0 using c# 3.0 along with MS Sql server Database 2008 R2.

I am looking for a good hosting which can provide unlimited bandwidth and good technical support (like Tele and Live Chat). I have discussion with few hosting companies they are recommending me to host my website on Cloud hosting. My technical question is will my website work on cloud hosting i tried to find relevant information on website but some of it is confusing.

As i mentioned above my application is developed around ASP.Net 4, FW4.0, C# and my application also uses session variable. Please suggest if my website will work or I have to make some changes to the application so that it will work on cloud hosting enviroment.

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/). It's a fully managed cloud platform that lets you easily deploy and scale .NET applications. Deployment happens using your favourite version control system and there's a large catalog of add-ons.

If your app uses session state, you have to manage that carefully so that state is shared between all instances running your applications. Here's a guide on [using Memcached for session state](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/tips-and-tricks/using-memcached-backed-sessionprovider).

(disclaimer, I'm co-founder of [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/))

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft have been banging a drum about their [Azure Platform](http://www.windowsazure.com/) that supports ASP.NET and SQL hosting.  Certainly appears to be scalable and obviously any pricing needs to be offset as you are not paying any hardware cost (although all of this will be virtualised tbh).

I am aware of genuine businesses using the platform in anger and they are reasonably positive but YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Windows Azure..try one of their free trials that is no-risk.  If you have an MSDN account, you can also get a perm discount (free if your website is small).

You can easily see what your costs would be using the Pricing Calculator:
[Windows Azure Pricing Calculator](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/)

(for example you had questions about bandwidth).

Azure is provided by Microsoft, therefore having a "full .NET stack" will pretty much work.  ASP.NET, C# etc are not going to be a problem.

SQL Server 2008 R2..there is SQL Azure and it has most of the features are present.  However, SQL Azure doesn't do some of the "advanced features" like full-text search, CLR types etc.
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/996.compare-sql-server-with-sql-azure.aspx